# Angular: Load bootstrap modal loaded with data of the element clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, scope, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of items which I display from a service, I use ng-repeat to display my data.
For any of these items I'd like to be able to open a bootstrap modal filled with data of the item clicked (within the scope of this item).

```
myApp.directive('openmodal', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('click', function(){ 
                $(element.attr('href')).modal();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle.net of my code here http://jsfiddle.net/echTw/2/

At the moment my bootstrap modal will only display only data from the first object of my JSON. How can I run bootstrap modal and load data within the scope of the element clicked (does Angular has something similar to this.$)?

**EDIT**

No I'm not using angular-strap. I tried to use directive and isolate the scope as suggested but the lightbox will still display data from the first element only (not sure why).

So I updated my code to use ng-click, a controller and also added dynamic ID to the modal to fix the issue:

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="show(task.id)">Show lightbox</a>
```

**Angular**

```
function TaskController($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;

    $scope.show = function(e){
        $('#myModal_'+e).modal();
        console.log('#myModal_'+e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think there is a couple of step missing here. Your Jsfiddle doesn't work at all so it is hard to really understand what your problem is. So I'll address every concern I can think you are missing.

First, ar you using [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)? It defines most directives for Bootstrap components and integrates better with "Angular Way".

Then, instead of using href (wich, in angular, can be manage with the [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)), you can use your scope to, for example, select the right item to show by passing it the id of the element

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn" openmodal>Open modal</a>
```

can become something like

```
 <a ng-click="show(item.id)">Show this item</a>
```

Where `show` is a function define in your controller that triggers the modal and selects the right item to display.

Then if you want to use it as a directive, you can inject this element in your directive and display it. You might need

```
return {
    scope: true, // Isolated scope -> not shared between all components
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 
       // ...
    },
};
```

Try something like and don't hesitate if you have any questions!

Answer (score -1):

you can try this simplest working code

HTML CODE:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnmargin' 
        data-toggle='modal' data-target='#cInfo' data-ng-click='moreinfo(customer)'>more info
</button>
```

Inside Controller code will be:

```
$scope.customerinfo=[];
$scope.moreinfo= function(customer){
  $scope.customerinfo= customer;
};
```

HTML Bootstrap Model code:

```
<!-- Modal start -->
<div class='modal fade' id='cinfo' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' 
     aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>
          <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
          <span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title text-danger' 
            id='myModalLabel'>customer info</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        {{customerinfo.firstName}}
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' 
                data-dismiss='modal'>close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal end -->
```